# How to get regular expression from grammar

Tags: regex, formal-languages

The grammar below is a regular grammar, 0 and 1 are terminal symbols, and S,A,B are non terminal symbols.

```
S → 0A | 1B | 0
A → 0A | 0S | 1B
B → 1B | 1 | 0
```

I'm trying to express this grammar as a regular expression, but I don't know if my solution is correct.

first,

- B = 1B + 1 + 0 =  1*(1+0)
- A = 0A + 0S + 1B = 0A + 00A + 01B + 00 + 1B = (0+00)A + (01 + 1)B + 00 = (0+00)A + (01 + 1)1*(1+0) + 00 = (0+00)*{(01 + 1)1*(1+0) + 00}

therefore,

- S = 0A + 1B + 0 = 0(0+00)*{(01 + 1)1*(1+0) + 00} + 1*(1+0) + 0

While solving the related problem so far, it appears so long and there is no complicated case, so I think there is a wrong part, but it is hard to find it. If there is any problem with my solution, I would appreciate it if you let me know.

Comment: Your analysis seems correct to me. There are some simplifications you could still make: `(0+00)*` is the same as `0*`, for example. Also, `0` at the end can also be accomplished by `1*(1+0)` so it's redundant to keep it there.

Comment: Does the formalism you use allow `?` for an optional character? If so, `(01+1)` is `0?1`.

Comment: `(01 + 1)` is preceeded by `00*` (after simplification and distribution), so really that's just `00*1`. You could reduce this expression a lot further I think.

Comment: @ChrisDodd It is my understanding that OP is using `+` to mean "or" in this question, in which case both expressions accept both `0` and `00`. I.e., by `(0+00)*`, I (and I believe OP) mean `(0|00)*` in typical programming language RE syntax.

Comment: Hint: I just worked through the whole RE, and it reduces to something that takes 9 characters to express.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know in detail! I'll revise it based on the information you gave me.